# Ruby on Rails routing with a period or special character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a route with special characters like . or : or spaces. However, when I pass: 12-Pizza.: One Two Three

I look at the log output and Params: {pie => "12-Pizza"} is what shows up. It seems to hate periods is there a way to make the routing system ignore this?

Comment: I tried to do something like this, but it did not work: get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions', :constraints => { :user => /[^\/]+/ }

Comment: You should add updates to your post directly in the post. There's an edit button near the bottom of your post to allow you to do so.